# Specify dependency implementation in constructor parameter

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Suppose I have an interface `IA`, two implementations `A1` and `A2` and a dependent class `B` that depends on `IA`. Two implementations of the same interface in Windsor container are registered like this:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IA>()
    .ImplementedBy<A1>());
container.Register(Component.For<IA>()
    .ImplementedBy<A2>());
```

Is there are way to specify which implementation to use **inside the dependent class** `B`?

For example in Autofac, I could use `KeyFilterAttribute` like this:

```
class B 
{
    ...
    public B([KeyFilter("A1")]IA a)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to achieve this, and which one is most suitable depends on the bigger context.

1. If you register the components one by one, like in the sample code in question [Windsor uses the first component registered as the default](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-one-by-one.md#register-more-components-for-the-same-service) for the service. So inside your `B` you're guaranteed to get the service implemented by `A1`.
2. To be explicit you can force a component to be the default (works for registering by convention too

.

```
container.Register(
   Component.For<IA>().ImplementedBy<A1>(),
   Component.For<IA>().ImplementedBy<A2>().IsDefault());
```

3. Or, looking at it from the consuming-end's perspective [you can configure `B` to pick either `A1` or `A2` regardless of the defaults](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-one-by-one.md#supplying-the-component-for-a-dependency-to-use-service-override) (which would be the closest to the Autofac

.

```
container.Register(
   Component.For<B>()         
      .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<IA, A1>))
```

Comment: I guess the answer is Windsor does not have a way to specify within the dependent class which implementation to use. I'll accept this as an answer.

Comment: It does. That's the 3rd option I presented. It's just in the registration, not as an attribute on the class itself, which may live in another assembly, not referencing Windsor. If you're really motivated to have an attribute, extending Windsor to support it would be literally under 10 LOC by creating one of these: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/componentmodel-construction-contributors.md

Comment: When I said "specify within the dependent class" I meant as in I can modify the class code but not the registration code (dynamically loaded plugins for example). Sorry if it's not clear enough. The link you provided pretty much solves this, thanks!